# About Fonts in the Preamble

Tags: fonts

In the past, I used MathType in WPS office for creating math documents. Now I'm using *TexMaths* in LibreOffice, which is a free alternative. In MathType, I have used fonts *Gentium Book Basic* and *Thames* to write math expressions. I would like keep this solution, is this possible?

Comment: Welcome, at the time being, i don't see the relation to LaTeX yet. Can you specify?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the font files, you can use them with XeLaTeX, as it supports TrueType fonts too. Though I am not sure about visual quality, "native" TeX fonts tend to be much better.

It is worth to take a look though, for example I am quite pleased with Linux Libertine and Biolinum.

The import would be quite simple in XeLaTeX:

```
\setromanfont{Gentium Book Basic}
\setmathfont{Thames}
```

There are solutions for pure LaTeX, but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Your answer is lacking essential information.  First, you should mention, that the `fontspec` package is required for `\setromanfont`.  Second, I guess that “Thames” is not a Unicode math font, which means that `unicode-math` is not viable and `mathspec` has to be used instead.  You might also want to expand the undersized code snippet to a fully fledged MWE.

Comment: I will add this info, as soon as I can